# How to get the selected 'labels' from lightning:dualListbox?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Looking at the [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_dualListbox.htm), it was pretty straightforward to get the 'values' of selected options in a lightning:dualListbox. But how can I get the **corresponding labels** without executing another SOQL?

> CONTROLLER JS:

```
({
    onChange: function (cmp, event) {
    // This returns all selected 'values'
    var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value"); // This works
    var selectedOptionLabel = event.getParam("label"); // How to accomplish this?
    }
})
```

I tried looking at the `selectedOptions` and `event` in console, but they all seem to carry just the values...?

```
var selectedOptions = component.get("v.selectedOptions");
console.log('-------> selectedOptions JSON = ' + JSON.stringify(selectedOptions, null, 2)); 

var selectedOptionsList = event.getParam("value");
console.log('-------> selectedOptionsList JSON = ' + JSON.stringify(selectedOptionsList, null, 2)); 

console.log('-------> event JSON = ' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
```

[image]

Comment: There's no point in blanking out ID values; they're completely useless outside of your org.

Comment: We are a super secure org so doing everything I can to stay out of trouble :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter the original option list, and optionally map them:

```
var values = event.getParam("value");
var labels = component.get("v.listOptions")
      .filter(option => values.indexOf(option.value) > -1)
      .map(option => option.label);
```

If you're not storing the values anywhere, but setting them directly, you can still interrogate the dualListbox for its options:

```
var values = event.getParam("value");
var labels = component.find("myDualListbox").get("v.options")
      .filter(option => values.indexOf(option.value) > -1)
      .map(option => option.label);
```